# Netsuite - Set line item value for department

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to make custom mass update on netsuite with JS script but its not working.

Code:

```
function updateDepartment(rec_type, rec_id)
{
  var transaction = nlapiLoadRecord(rec_type, rec_id);
  transaction.setLineItemValue ('item','department', nlapiGetContext().getSetting('SCRIPT','custscript_dept_update'));
  nlapiSubmitRecord(transaction, false, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nlobjRecord.setLineItemValue needs a line number. You'd need to do something like:

```
var dept = nlapiGetContext().getSetting('SCRIPT','custscript_dept_update');
for(var i = transaction.getLineItemCount('item'); i> 0; i--){
  transaction.setLineItemValue('item', 'department', i, dept);
}
```

Comment: Hello I used below code, it works but not changing the department.                               `function updateDepartment(rec_type, rec_id)
     {
    var transaction = nlapiLoadRecord(rec_type, rec_id);
      var dept = nlapiGetContext().getSetting('SCRIPT','custscript_dept_update');
for(var i = transaction.getLineItemCount('item'); i> 0; i--){
  transaction.setLineItemValue('item', 'department', i, dept);
}
  }`

Comment: You still need to submit the record that you loaded; you have `nlapiSubmitRecord` in your question, but then I don't see it in your comment.

Comment: Note that line items are 1-indexed, not 0-indexed.  bknights has it right but just to point that out -- not obvious when everything else in Javascript is 0-based.